# Chrome Sender: media.playerState is not properly updated

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm working on Chrome Sender application now and noticed that `media.playerState` was not properly updated to `chrome.cast.media.PlayerState.PLAYING` when play request is successfully executed. I understand that it's possible to subscribe to media state update via `media.addUpdateListener(onMediaUpdate);` but it's not very convenient. Are there any plans to make API more consistent?

```js
/**
 * @param {chrome.cast.media.Media} media
 * @return {Promise.defer}
 */
function playMedia(media) {
  let playDefer = Promise.defer();
  let playRequest = new chrome.cast.media.PlayRequest();

  media.play(playRequest, onPlaySuccess.bind(null, playDefer, media), onPlayError); 

  return playDefer;
}

/**
 * @param {Promise.defer} defer
 * @param {chrome.cast.media.Media} media
 */
function onPlaySuccess(defer, media) {
  // Actually `media.playerState` is still chrome.cast.media.PlayerState.PAUSED
  // Is it expected behaviour? 
  console.log('play request success', media.playerState === chrome.cast.media.PlayerState.PLAYING);
  defer.resolve(media);
}

/**
 * @param {chrome.cast.Error} error
 */
function onPlayError(error) {
  console.log(error.code, error.description);
}
```

Comment: I believe using update listeners is the recommended way to do it. Why do you say it isn't convenient?

Comment: Well, i think it's just counter-intuitive, isn't it? What's the purpose of `chrome.cast.media.PlayRequest` object then? I think it would make more sense if that request was resolved when the playback is actually started instead of just being notified about the fact that request reached the receiver app.

Comment: Since `chrome.cast.media.PlayRequest` is just a request to play the media,  multiple senders can request to play media, and other sender-receiver communications may occur behind the scenes, it's better to just check for changes to the player state using the update listener as opposed to after completion of the play request. You can check out some of the sample apps, such as [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android), to get a better idea of how the player state is updated.

Comment: That makes sense. I just didn't take into account multi-sender scenario.